# After Edit The Login Detail I Am No longer Able To Login Again

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

**register page**
This is  register page which is working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>REGISTER HERE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<?php 

<?php 
require_once("inc/connection.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$password= $_POST['password'];
$day = $_POST['dob'];
$month=$_POST['dob2'];
$year = $_POST['dob3'];
if(isset($_POST['gender'])){
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
}
if(isset($_FILES['upload'])){
$filename = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
$filetmp = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
$filetype = $_FILES['upload']['type'];
$fileError= $_FILES['upload']['error'];
$filesize= $_FILES['upload']['size'];
}
$max=1000000;
if(!empty($name) && !empty($password) && !empty($day) && !empty($month) && !empty($year) && isset($gender)){
if(!empty($password)){
$password=sha1($password);
if(!empty($name)){
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM govtup WHERE name='$name'");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($count==1) {
echo "This name is already registered please choose another username";
}else{
if($fileError==0){
if($filesize<=$max){
if (($filetype=="text/plain") || ($filetype=="application/msword")){
move_uploaded_file($filetmp, "document/".rand(100,9999999).time()."$filename");
$query2=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO govtup(name,password,day,month,year,gender) VALUES ('$name','$password','$day','$month','$year','$gender')");
if($query2){
unset($name);
header("Location: login.php");
echo "Successfully registered";
}else{
echo "not registered";
}
}else{
echo "only txt and doc file allowed";
}
}else{
echo "The file is too big please choose filesize less than 1mb";
}
}else{
echo "please choose a txt or doc file to upload";
}
}
}
}
}else{
echo "Please fill all the field";
}
}

?>
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="" id="form">
<label class="lb">USERNAME</label><p>
<input type="text" name="name" class="int" placeholder="Please Enter Your Name" value="<?php echo isset($name)?$name:"" ?>" /><p>

<label class="lb">PASSWORD</label><p>
<input type="password" name="password" class="int" placeholder="Please Enter Your Password"/><p>

<label class="lb">D.O.B</label><p>
<select name="dob">

<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select name="dob2">

<option value="jan">jan</option>
<option value="feb">feb</option>
<option value="mar">mar</option>
<option value="april">april</option>
</select>
<select name="dob3">

<option value="1992">1992</option>
<option value="1993">1993</option>
<option value="1994">1994</option>
<option value="1994">1995</option>
</select>

<P>
<label class="lb">MALE</label>
<input type="radio"  name="gender" value="male" />
<label class="lb">FEMALE</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/>
<p>
<label class="lb">UPLOAD FILE</label>
<!-- <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000"/> -->
<input type="file" class="int" name="upload" /><p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register Me">&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="login.php" style="font-size:20px;">Login Here..</a>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Login Page**
This is login.php it is working fine till i am just register and log out then login but when i login and edit detail in my edit.php page and then log-out after logout i am unable to login again says 'email or password combination is wrong' which is a message whenever name and password don't match.

```
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>REGISTER HERE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<?php 
require_once("inc/connection.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['name']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,sha1($_POST['password']));
if(!empty($name) && !empty($password)){
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM govtup WHERE name='$name' and password='$password'");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count==1){
$data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
unset($data['password']);
if(isset($_POST['keep'])){
setcookie("usercookie",$data['name'],time()+(60));
}
$_SESSION['usersession']=$data;
header("Location: index.php");
$_SESSION['msg']="You have been successfully logedin!";
}else{
echo "Your name and password combination is wrong";
}
}else{
echo "Please Enter your login name and password";
}
}

?>
<form method="post" action="" id="form">
<p>
<label class="lb">USERNAME</label><p>
<input type="text" name="name" class="int" placeholder="Please Enter Your Name" value="<?php echo isset($name)?$name:"" ?>" /><p>

<label class="lb">PASSWORD</label><p>
<input type="password" name="password" class="int" placeholder="Please Enter Your Password"/><p>
Remember me:<input type="checkbox" name="keep"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="log in">&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="register.php" style="font-size:20px;">Register Here..</a><p>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit.php page**
This is edit.php page which creating problem so please help me out for solve this problem the problem is whenever i edit any of the user detail in this page and then logout and try to login again it's not allow me to login again says 'email and password combination is wrong"(this is echo msg).I am trying to solve this from the morning but didn't find out where problem is.

```
<?php 

session_start();
require_once("inc/connection.php");
if(empty($_SESSION['usersession']))
{
   header("Location: login.php");
}

if(isset($_SESSION['msg']))
{
   echo $_SESSION['msg'];
   unset($_SESSION['msg']);
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>REGISTER HERE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<?php 
    require_once("inc/connection.php");
    if(isset($_POST['update']))
    {
       $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['name']);
       $password= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,sha1($_POST['password']));
       $day = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['dob']);
       $month=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['dob2']);
       $year = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['dob3']);
       $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['gender']);
       $id=$_SESSION['usersession']['id'];

       if(isset($_POST['gender']))
       {
          $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['gender']);
       }
       if(isset($_FILES['upload']))
       {
          $filename = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
          $filetmp = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
          $filetype = $_FILES['upload']['type'];
          $fileError= $_FILES['upload']['error'];
          $filesize= $_FILES['upload']['size'];
       }
       $max=1000000;
       if(!empty($name && $password && $day && $month && $year))
       {
          if(!empty($password))
          {
             $password=sha1($password);
             if(!empty($name))
             {
                $query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM govtup WHERE name='$name'");
                $count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
                if($count==1)
                {
                   echo "This username is already registered please choose another one";
                }
                else
                {
                   if($fileError==0)
                   {
                      if($filesize<=$max)
                      {
                         if($filetype="text/plain" || $filetype="application/msword")
                         {
                            move_uploaded_file($filetmp, "document/".rand(100,9999999).time()."$filename");
                            $query2=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE govtup SET name='$name',password='$password',day='$day',month='$month',year='$year',gender='$gender' WHERE id='$id'");
                            if($query2)
                            {
                               header("Location: index.php");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                               echo "Not Updated";
                            }
                            $_SESSION['msg']="You detail Updated";
                            $_SESSION['usersession']['name']=$name;
                         }
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="" id="form">
<label class="lb">USERNAME</label><p>
<input type="text" name="name" class="int" placeholder="Please Enter Your Name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usersession']['name']; ?>" /><p>

<label class="lb">PASSWORD</label><p>
<input type="password" name="password" class="int" placeholder="Please Enter Your Password"/><p>

<label class="lb">D.O.B</label><p>
<select name="dob">
<option><?php echo $_SESSION['usersession']['dob']; ?></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select name="dob2">
<option><?php echo $_SESSION['usersession']['dob2']; ?></option>
<option value="jan">jan</option>
<option value="feb">feb</option>
<option value="mar">mar</option>
<option value="april">april</option>
</select>
<select name="dob3">
<option><?php echo $_SESSION['usersession']['dob3']; ?></option>
<option value="1992">1992</option>
<option value="1993">1993</option>
<option value="1994">1994</option>
<option value="1994">1995</option>
</select>
your current dob:<?php echo $_SESSION['usersession']['day']."-".$_SESSION['usersession']['month']."-".$_SESSION['usersession']['year']; ?><p>

<P>
<label class="lb">MALE</label>
<input type="radio"  name="gender" value="male" />
<label class="lb">FEMALE</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/>
<p>
<label class="lb">UPLOAD FILE</label>
<!-- <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000"/> -->
<input type="file" class="int" name="upload"/><p>
<input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code is formatted more than bad

Comment: which one i am beginner in just start learning it and did you find what is the problem in edit.php which creating problem

Comment: HERE is css if you need body{padding: 0;margin: 0;}*{font-family: verdana;}#wrapper{width: 1000px;}#form{width: 600px; border: 1px solid black; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 100px; margin-left: 400px; padding: 30px; background: #6ac;}.lb{font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;}.int{width: 500px; height: 30px;}

Comment: i did something wrong in edit.php which i didn't get so can please just tell me what wrong in that edit.php code which is not allow me to login again after logout.I aligned all the code to left because the site is not allowing me to post my nested code here.

Comment: Is your database getting updated after you edit the details ?

Comment: yes database is updating the detail.

Comment: echo `$query ` in `login.php` to see whether a correct query is fired on the db or not.

Comment: it show s this."mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 7 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 ) ".

Comment: replace `$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,sha1($_POST['password']));` to `$password= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);` in `edit.php`. You are applying `SHA1` two times in `edit.php`

Comment: i also echo $count to check if the raw exists or not and i shows 0 row exists while the row is exists in database.

Comment: See me edited comment and apply that change. See if it works or not now.

Comment: hey men you are right problem solved the was with "$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,sha1($_POST['password']));SHA1"

Comment: can you help me with one more that i am using DOB system so i want make it like facebook. WHENEVER A user edit there date of birth detail on facebook they always show there old DOB in drop down menu mine is also show but it shows every value twice like 1-jan-1992 then it shows in day 1,1,2 and so on how can i fix it

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understood your problem. Can you please explain it again in detail.

Comment: seems he already solved it, putting the CSS in the comment section really helped

Comment: my problem is is use <select> tag to add user DATE OF BIRTH i maid three <select> drop down one for DAY,one for Month and one for YEAR.once i registered user and go to edit.php for edit my detail i don't show user day,month and year which user selected on the time of register for that i use session[]['dob'] in first <option> so it show the user DOB in first <option> but if user birth day is 1 then in drop down it show 1,1,2,3,4 means show current dob of user and then all values of <option>

Comment: but in facebook it shows only all the values like 1,2,3,4 the day of bith is selected and in facebook. when user click on drop down button it only highlight the user day of birth like 1(highlighted),2,3,4.hope you understand :D

Comment: Can you please update your `edit.php` with the code generating duplicate value?

Comment: i just edit the code of edit.php check the all first <option>tag after all<select>tag.that was only one line which is to display the value putted by user on the time of registered.

Comment: TOO GOOD men each problem solved thanx a lot...i appreciate  your help and the time you gave me.....thank you soooooooo much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,sha1($_POST['password']));` to `$password= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);` in `edit.php`.

You are applying `SHA1` two times in `edit.php`. So it is encrypting the password two times before inserting into the database. When you login, you encrypt it just once, so the password is not matching and hence, you get the error.

For the second problem, replace the code for `<option>` with the below code:

```
<select name="dob">
<? php
   $i;
   for($i = 1; $i < 31; $i++)
   {
        if($i == $_SESSION['usersession']['dob'];)
           echo '<option selected="selected" value = "'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>'

        else
           echo '<option value = "'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>'
   }
?>
</select>
```